# Query databases on different servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I create a query that will find all the databases on different servers?

I have four servers,  PRDSVR, UATSVR, DEVSVR, TRNSVR; with either copies of the same database on each server or standalone databases that may only be on one or two servers.

I would like to create a query that searches for all databases, listing the server, databases on that server, and the size of each of the databases.  How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four part naming convention.

Add a linked server that will define the security context for connecting, then refer to `PRDSVR.master.sys.databases` and the like.

Comment: Using your suggestion I've used the following query;

Comment: SELECT    mf.database_id,
   mf.name, 
   mf.size
FROM    [LINKEDSERVER1].master.sys.master_files AS mf
WHERE    mf.file_id = 1;    Would this work or would this give misleading results?

Comment: That should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to create a query that searches for all databases, listing the server, databases on that server, and the size of each of the databases. How can I achieve this?

The easiest way of doing is using SSMS --> Registered Servers

[image]

[image]

Below is the code that will give you the database filesize, space used and free space:

```
DECLARE
    @SqlStatement nvarchar(MAX)
    ,@DatabaseName sysname;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#DatabaseSpace') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DatabaseSpace;

CREATE TABLE #DatabaseSpace(
    DATABASE_NAME   sysname
    ,LOGICAL_NAME   sysname
    ,FILE_SIZE_MB   decimal(12, 2)
    ,SPACE_USED_MB  decimal(12, 2)
    ,FREE_SPACE_MB  decimal(12, 2)
    ,FILE_NAME      sysname
    );

DECLARE DatabaseList CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT name FROM sys.databases;

OPEN DatabaseList;
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseList INTO @DatabaseName;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;
    SET @SqlStatement = N'USE '
        + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)
        + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)
        + N'INSERT INTO #DatabaseSpace
    SELECT
        [DATABASE_NAME] = DB_NAME()
        ,[LOGICAL_NAME] = f.name
        ,[FILE_SIZE_MB] = CONVERT(decimal(12,2),round(f.size/128.000,2))
        ,[SPACE_USED_MB] = CONVERT(decimal(12,2),round(fileproperty(f.name,''SpaceUsed'')/128.000,2))
        ,[FREE_SPACE_MB] = CONVERT(decimal(12,2),round((f.size-fileproperty(f.name,''SpaceUsed''))/128.000,2))
        ,[FILENAME] = f.name
    FROM sys.database_files f;';

    EXECUTE(@SqlStatement);

END
CLOSE DatabaseList;
DEALLOCATE DatabaseList;

SELECT * FROM #DatabaseSpace;

DROP TABLE #DatabaseSpace;;
GO
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create the query to call [sys.databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) and [sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190326.aspx) on one server.

Then you can either use SSMS with a http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743.aspx to run it on multiple servers simultaneously, or use something like linked servers and [execute at](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) or [openquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) or four part naming - ideally, designate one server your "monitoring" server, and set up SQL Server Agent jobs on all four to put information into one table so you can watch trends.